Is it possible to create a type in .net that acts just like a literal string?
Values of literal strings in .NET are

immutable
if equal they always point to the same memory location

That's why equal and not equal operations for those string values in .NET are fast - they are not comparing the text just the pointer addresses.
I now want to create an object that acts exactly the same way. If the object is of same value it should point to the same memory location.
Is this even possible without using a very memory intensive hash table?
I fear that string functionality is done by some compiler magic that cannot be achieved by C# code.

Equal string doesn't necessary point to the same memory location: if st1.Equals(st2) == true it doesn't mean that ReferenceEquals(st1, st2) == true

It sounds like XY problem, what X problem do you have?

https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/51cf7850defa8a17d815b4700b67116e3fa283c2/mscorlib/system/string.cs#L570 shows it still going to search by characters if the reference doesn't match https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/51cf7850defa8a17d815b4700b67116e3fa283c2/mscorlib/system/string.cs#L364 so string objects with equal characters aren't guaranteed to have the same reference

To prove that your second assumption is not true, try ReferenceEquals(1000.ToString(), 1000.ToString())

what I think OP is after is the string.Intern functionality (that he mistakenly thinks applies always). There is indeed a lot of magic there + a hash-table.

How does the object that you want to do this look? Why do you want to do it?

@Ivan Petrov you may be right. I look into it.

@Magnus I do have immutable structs I want to boost performance by only do ReferenceEqual checks instead of Equal checks that have to compare every property in the object

@IamanSwtrse you can check this answer to a new question I created that hopefully won't be closed...

But structs are value types, reference equals makes no sense.
